# How to estimate motion with FTT and Cross-Correlation?

Tags: python, image-processing, fft, cross-correlation

I'm working in the estimation of cloud displacement for wind energy purposes with RGB GOES satellital images. I find the following the methodology from this paper "An Automated Technique for Obtaining Cloud Motion From Geosynchronous Satellite Data Using Cross Correlation" to achieve it. I don't know if this is a good way to compute this. The code bassically gets the cross correlation from the Fourier Transform to calculate cloud displacement between `roi_a` and `roi_b` images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_a = cv.imread('2019.1117.1940.goes-16.rgb.tif', 0)
img_b = cv.imread('2019.1117.1950.goes-16.rgb.tif', 0)

roi_a = img_a[700:900, 1900:2100]
roi_b = img_b[700:900, 1900:2100]

def Fou(image):
    fft_roi= np.fft.fft2(image)
    return fft_roi

def inv_Fou(C_w):
    c_t = np.fft.ifft2(C_w)
    c_t = np.abs(c_t)
    return c_t

#Step 1: gets the FFT
G_t0 = Fou(roi_a)##t_0    
fft_roiA_conj = np.conj(G_t0) #Conjugate
G_t1 = Fou(roi_b)##t_1

#Step 2: Compute C(m, v)
prod = np.dot(fft_roiA_conj, G_t1)

#Step 3: Perform the inverse FFT
inv = inv_Fou(prod)

plt.imshow(inv, cmap = 'gray', )
plt.title('C (m,v) --> Cov(p,q)')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([]) 
plt.show()

#Step 4: Compute cross correlation coefficient and the maximum cross correlation coefficient
def rms(sigma):
    "Compute the standar deviation of an image"
    rms = np.std(sigma)
    return rms

R_t = inv / (rms(roi_a) * rms(roi_b))
```

[image]

This is the first time that I use FFT on images, so I have some questions about it:

- I don't add fftshift, is this can affect the result?
- What is difference between use np.dot in step 2 and simple '*', like `prod = fft_roiA_conj * G_t1`
- How to interpret the image result (C(m, v) -> Cov (p, q)) from step 3?
- How can I obtain the maximum coefficient p' and q' (maximum coefficient of x and y directions) from `R_t`?

Answer (score 1):

1 - `fftshift` is a circular rotation, if you have a two sided signal you are computing the correlation is shifted (circularly), what is important is that you map your indices to displacements correctly, with or without `fftshift`.

2 - [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is the matrix product (equivalent to `@` operator for recent python versions), and the `*` operator does element-wise multiplication, in my understanding you want the element-wise product at step 2.

3 - Once you correct the step 2 you will have an image such that `inv[i, j]` the correlation of the immage `roi_a` and the image `roi_b` rolled by `i` rows and j columns

To answer the last question I will workout an example.

I will use the image scipy.misc.face, it is a RGB image, so it brings three matrices that are highly correlated.

```py
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = scipy.misc.face()
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.subplot(131), plt.imshow(f[:,:, 0])
plt.subplot(132), plt.imshow(f[:,:, 1])
plt.subplot(133), plt.imshow(f[:,:, 2])
```

[image: The three channels of face]

The function `img_corr`combine the three steps of the cross correlation (for images of the same size), notice that I am use `rfft2` and `irfft2`, this are the FFT for real data, that take advantage of symmetry in the frequency domain.

```py
def img_corr(foi_a, foi_b):
    return np.fft.irfft2(np.fft.rfft2(foi_a) * np.conj(np.fft.rfft2(foi_b)))
```

```py
C = img_corr(f[:,:,1], f[:,:,2])
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(C), plt.title('FFT indices')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(np.fft.fftshift(C, (0, 1))), plt.title('fftshift ed version')
```

[image: The cross correlation for the green and blue channels]

To retrieve the position

```
# this returns the indice in the vector of all pixels
best_corr = np.argmax(C)
# unravel index gives the 2D index
best_pos = np.unravel_index(best_corr, C.shape)

# this get the positions as a fraction of the image size
relative_pos = [np.fft.fftfreq(size)[index] for index, size in zip(best_pos, C.shape)]
```

I hope this completes the answer.